# Python3.9.6 interpreter does not appear in pycharm

Tags: 20.04, python, python3, pycharm

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and just update python3.8 to python3.9 as you can see below

[image: python version]

The problem is now that i want to use Pycharm i only get the python3.8 interpreter, my question how can i add the python3.9.. i already tried several thign but strill does not recognize the interpreter. This is how it appears to me in Pycharm CE.

[image: pycharm]

Answer (score 1):

Since you made `python3.9` the default version of `python3`, the `/usr/bin/python3` shown in PyCharm should be Python 3.9.

You have not mentioned how you installed `python3.9`. It is dangerous to replace default version of Python in Ubuntu, as certain system components may stop working (in case there are no issues, you need not worry).

It is a good idea to install it with `sudo apt install python3.9` and call it with the command `python3.9` (and it should then show up in PyCharm as `/usr/bin/python3.9`).

Comment: thank you soo much, i can fix it